# Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, draw

So I've been working on a homework on abstraction for my programming class and fell into a problem. The goal for me right now is to be able to use abstraction, then later be able to draw with rectangles and ovals a simple city, like a rectangular building or a oval light on a light post.

The error I am receiving when I compile is: MyTestApp.Rectangle is not abstract and does not override abstract method drawEllipse(java.awt.Graphics) in MyTestApp.Shape. This Error shows up on the line "class Rectangle extends Shape{" right below the class Shape.

My question is what am I doing wrong with my abstraction? I've been messing with the constructors and draw() methods in classes Rectangle and Ellipse for a while now and still to no luck happen to find a solution.

Code is below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyTestApp extends JPanel {
    Rectangle rect;
    Ellipse oval;
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        MyTestApp myTestApp = new MyTestApp ();
        myTestApp.test();
    }

    public MyTestApp () { //creates the jframe
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyClass Driver");
        setBackground(new Color(200, 250, 200));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void delay(int msecs) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(msecs);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {//paints the rectangle and ellipse
        super.paint(g);
        if (rect != null)
            rect.drawRectangle(g);
        if (oval != null)
            oval.drawEllipse(g);
    }

    public void test() {//gives the x/y position, width/height, and fill/outline color for the rectangle and oval
        delay(1000);
        rect = new Rectangle(20, 30, 23, 75, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE);
        oval = new Ellipse(10, 10, 10 , 34, Color.RED, Color.MAGENTA);
        repaint();
    }

    public abstract class Shape{//abstract class Shape that sets the x/y, width/height, and colors for the shapes
        private int x, y, width, height;
        private Color fillColor;
        private Color outlineColor;
        public Shape(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color fillColor, Color outlineColor) {
            setXY(x, y);
            setSize(width, height);
            setFillColor(fillColor);
            setOutlineColor(outlineColor);  
        }

        public boolean setXY(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            return true;
        }

        public void setSize(int width, int height) {
            if (width > 0)
                this.width = width;
            if (height > 0)
                this.height = height;
        }

        public boolean setFillColor(Color fillColor){
            if (fillColor == null) return false;
            this.fillColor = fillColor; 
            return true;
        }

        public boolean setOutlineColor(Color outlineColor){
            if (outlineColor == null) return false;
            this.outlineColor = outlineColor; 
            return true;
        }

        public Color getFillColor() {
            return fillColor;
        } 

        public Color getOutlineColor() {
            return outlineColor;
        } 

        public abstract void drawRectangle(Graphics g);//do i need two?
        public abstract void drawEllipse(Graphics g);//do i need both?
    }
    class Rectangle extends Shape{//!!!!!!!!!! where the error shows
        public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color fillColor, Color outlineColor) {
            super(x, y, width, height, fillColor, outlineColor);
        }

        public void drawRectangle(Graphics g){//draws the retangle
            g.setColor(fillColor);
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
            g.setColor(outlineColor);
            g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }
    class Ellipse extends Shape{
        public Ellipse(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color fillColor, Color outlineColor) {
            super(x, y, width, height, fillColor, outlineColor);
        }

        public void drawEllipse(Graphics g){//draws the ellipse
            g.setColor(fillColor);
            g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
            g.setColor(outlineColor);
                g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks for reading and helping!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both classes Rectangle and Ellipse need to override both of the abstract methods.

To work around this, you have 3 options:

- Add the two methods
- Make each class that extends Shape abstract
- Have a single method that does the function of the classes that will extend Shape, and override that method in Rectangle and Ellipse, for example:

  ```
  abstract class Shape {
      // ...
      void draw(Graphics g);
  }
  ```

And

```
    class Rectangle extends Shape {
        void draw(Graphics g) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Finally

```
    class Ellipse extends Shape {
        void draw(Graphics g) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

And you can switch in between them, like so:

```
    Shape shape = new Ellipse();
    shape.draw(/* ... */);

    shape = new Rectangle();
    shape.draw(/* ... */);
```

Again, just an example.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to take advantage of polymorphic behavior, you need to ensure that the methods visible to outside classes (that need polymorphism) have the same signature. That means they need to have the same name, number and order of parameters, as well as the parameter types.

In your case, you might do better to have a generic `draw()` method, and rely on the subclasses (`Rectangle`, `Ellipse`) to implement the `draw()` method as what you had been thinking of as "drawEllipse" and "drawRectangle".